# How to add multi select checkbox at the top of the listview Visual Studio LightSwitch

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, visual-studio-lightswitch

I am using Visual Studio LightSwitch 2015

I am having a ListView in the Screen as below when I run the project

[Countries View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbpfX.jpg)

Design View is as below

[Countries Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp3SM.jpg)

How can I add checkbox here in design view and on click of it how to select/deselect the checkboxes in the ListView?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something like add custom control and using jquery script.

Comment: I am ok in using third party javascript frameworks also. Please help me out.